# Vertically align multiple spans inside a div - Different behavior in different browsers

Tags: html, css, drupal-7

I have 3 spans inside a single div. Chrome shows all the three spans vertically aligned at the center like this:

[image]

But this is what happens in Firefox:

[image]

Below is the code for the div which contains the following: quantity label, - button, text field & + button:

```
<div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-quantity">
    <label for="edit-quantity">Quantity </label>
    <span class="commerce-quantity-plusminus-link commerce-quantity-plusminus-link-decrease commerce-quantity-plusminus-link-disabled"><a href="/myWebsite/node/12" class="button" onclick="Drupal.commerce_extra_quantity_quantity('#edit-quantity', -1); return false;">-</a></span>
    <span class="inline-block-text-box"><input type="text" id="edit-quantity" name="quantity" value="1" size="5" maxlength="128" class="form-text"></span>
    <span class="commerce-quantity-plusminus-link commerce-quantity-plusminus-link-increase commerce-quantity-plusminus-link-disabled"><a href="/myWebsite/node/12" class="button" onclick="Drupal.commerce_extra_quantity_quantity('#edit-quantity', 1); return false;">+</a></span>
</div>
```

And below is the only CSS which is applicable for it:

```
.inline-block-text-box
{
    /* Raj: To show increment and decrement buttons in same line along with the text field */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Is there anything with which the problem can be fixed?

Comment: `vertical-align: middle` all the inline-block elements

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/dLzvL7t2/

Comment: Otherwise, we will need the rest of the css associate with that html.

Comment: @TinyGiant - vertical-align: middle fixed it. If you could post and answer I will accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> #### [vertical-align: middle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)
>
> The vertical-align CSS property specifies the vertical alignment of an inline or table-cell box.
>
> - **Middle**
>   Aligns the middle of the element with the baseline plus half the x-height of the parent.

If you set each `inline-block` element to `vertical-align: middle` then all of those elements will be vertically centered in reference to the **parent** element.

```
.inline-block-text-box {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Still wondering why the behavior is different in Chrome and Firefox without explicit mention of vertical-align?

Comment: I don't know exactly in this case, there could be many causes, I would have to look at the rest of the source to make a better determination.

Comment: what about my container is a <a> and inside svg  and span, looks dont' work

Comment: @stack I'd have to see an example of it not working to tell you why.